# List all the Components under Azure's Contributor Role (Microsoft.Web/sites/*)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-role-environment

I am making a user on Azure Active Directory, and want him to access only limited things inside Azure Web Apps. For a contributor role in Azure, the contributor has the following Actions assigned to it,

Microsoft.Web/sites/*

Which means it can do anything within the Web Apps.

Is there a way I can see individual components that lie under "Microsoft.Web/sites/ " (for example Microsoft.Web/sites/start) and so on? so that I can assign specific roles under Microsoft.Web/sites/ accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with Azure PowerShell:

```
Get-AzProviderOperation -OperationSearchString 'Microsoft.Web/sites/*' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Operation
```

appears you can do more or less the same with az: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/provider/operation?view=azure-cli-latest#az-provider-operation-show